# Is it possible to use a class property type to constrain another property's type?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm looking to make a class that basically allows array members in one property to declare a type constraint that is then enforced on another property of the containing class. Is something like this possible in Typescript?

```js
class Container<B> {
  thingsA: SomeTypeA<B>[]; // replace `B` with something that means "this array composes B as an intersection of its members"
  thingB: B;

  constructor(a: SomeTypeA<B>[], b: B) {
    this.thingsA = a;
    this.thingB = b;
  }
}

class Member1 implements SomeType<{ keyA: string }> {
}

class Member2 implements SomeType<{ keyB: string }> {
}

const x = new Container([new Member1(), new Member2()], { keyA: 'test1', keyB: 'test2' }); // valid

const y = new Container([new Member1(), new Member2()], { keyA: 'test1' } // invalid, B requires `keyB`
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"this array composes B as a union of it's members"*?

Comment: As in, one array member has the type parameter `{ x: string }`, another has `{ y: string }` and thus when this array is passed into `Container<B>`, `B` becomes `{ x: string, y: string }`, which then constrains `thingB` so that it **must** contain both `x` and `y`

Comment: @hmind Do you think you could clarify that to mean which properties on `Container` are what types?

Comment: Should SomeTypeA be SomeType?

Comment: What's `SomeType`? And how do `class Member1` and `class Member2` implement it without bodies?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wOPa6N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.